# Is it possible to prevent EF7 contexts from closing the connection after their work within a transaction?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, transactions, dbcontext, ef-core-7.0

## One connection across multiple contexts in EF7.

I want to make a single transaction that runs multiple contexts in parallel, but I get the following error.

"Invalid operation. The connection is closed. Entity framework 7."

I realized that the contexts close the connection after they have worked. Can contexts not close the connection after their work?

I tried to do so. What am I missing?

## Edit

I managed to solve this problem by adding "MultipleActiveResultSets=True" in the DB connection string.
Thanks to all!

```
try
{
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.ConnectionString))
    {
        var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyContext>()
            .UseSqlServer(connection)
            .Options;
        connection.Open();
        using (var transaction = connection.BeginTransaction())
        {
            var Tasks = new List<Task>();

            Tasks.Add(Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Parallel.ForEach(someList1, groping =>
                {
                    using (var db = new MyContext(options))
                    {
                        db.Database.UseTransaction(transaction);
                        //adding to db someList1
                    }
                });
            }));

            Tasks.Add(Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Parallel.ForEach(someList2, groping =>
                {
                    using (var db = new MyContext(options))
                    {
                        db.Database.UseTransaction(transaction);
                        //adding to db someList2
                    }
                });
            }));

            Task.WaitAll(Tasks.ToArray());

            transaction.Commit();
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception)
{
}
```

Comment: The code is in a using block which will automatically dispose the object when leaving using block.  There are two solutions. 1)  Remove the using block.  You probably want to close object to prevent memory leaks elsewhere in the code.  Remember there is a connection pool in the library. 2) Put you additional connection inside the using block.

Comment: What's the idea of using one connection instance? What do you think will happen when two threads use the same connection?